# Retrieve second parameter from stringCollection

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

How can I retrieve the second value of stringCollection, like

```
['Ana', 'Clara]
```

And output this values in two different claims, e.g:

```
<ClaimType Id="firstName"/> // Ana
<ClaimType Id="lastName"/> // Clara
```

I searched for and nowhere describes how split stringCollection into claims, there is a way?

(Documentation explains only about how get the first item)

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/stringcollection-transformations

Comment: Yes, sadly, the only way I have found to do it is to call a REST API.

Comment: I think it's the only way currently. @rbrayb Can you add an answer due to there is no other solution?